# Azure DevOps: How to create a folder in GIT repo with REST API repo

Tags: git, rest, azure-devops, azure-repos

I want to create a folder hierarchy in a GIT repository on Azure Devops using the REST API. (automated via a script)

The docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 provide only examples how you can create files, but not folders.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I hope this might help you with your topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258399/how-do-i-create-a-folder-in-a-github-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Git tracks files in a tree structure. If there is no file (leaf), there is no folder (tree-branch).

So you'll need to add at least one file to the empty folder.

Hence the way to create a folder with the REST API, is to create a file with a new folder as its root.

Comment: OK, creating a file and providing the complete path also creates all required folders.

Comment: how to clone repo to local folder using rest api ?

Comment: @Neo you don't.

Comment: clone i mean download all repo files folder using rest api?

Comment: @neo https://stackoverflow.com/a/66099760/736079

Answer (score 1):

This thread might help you out with your problem:

[How do I create a folder in a GitHub repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258399/how-do-i-create-a-folder-in-a-github-repository)

Basicly use / in the file name field to create folder(s), e.g. typing folder1/file1 in the file name field will create a folder folder1 and a file file1.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31757739)

Comment: @KuroNeko i posted the Link - then a summary with the fix